# remote portforwarding ssh in bash script (in background)

Tags: bash, ssh, background

Is there an easy way to run the ssh command and execute the "chromium" command after this on my local machine?

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh somehost -L 3005:127.0.0.1:6005
chromium "http://127.0.0.1:3001/"
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick with `sleep`:

```
timeout=15
ssh somehost -f -L 3005:127.0.0.1:6005 sleep $timeout
chromium "http://127.0.0.1:3005/"
```

Tunnel will be closed after `$timeout` seconds but if it's used it'll stay open.